# How to fix length of numeric regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose I want only digital/numeric value (No Special character or alphabet)

So, the regular expression will be `^[0-9]`

If I want a fix length of 6, what regular expression I should use?

Example: 555333, 111222

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `^[0-9]{6}$`

- `^` beginning
- `[0-9]` digit 0 to 9 (alternatively you could use `[\d]`)
- `{6}` appears exactly 6 times
- `$` end of string